# Universal Basic Income (UBI) policy proposals optimal hours worked and consumption

Tags: microeconomics, utility, labor-economics, consumption

can someone please help me check my work for this question? I want to make sure I did it correctly.

Question:

[image]

Work:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

That's correct, but it would be easier and faster to use

(i) $v=u^3=CL^2$ instead of $u$ as your utility function (which is allowed since $v$ is a positive transformation of $u$), and

(ii) the rule that in the optimum the ratio of marginal utilities equals the ratio of prices. This immediately gives you $7.5L=2C$, and substituting $2C$ for the $7.5L$ in the budget constraint then yields the solution.